# Error al pasar cadena de strings a otra activity

Tags: java, android

Tengo este código para recibir una cadena de strings que pase desde otra activity.

```
TextView infoEnviada;
    infoEnviada = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reslt);
    String[] array = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("resultados");
    infoEnviada.setText(array);
}
```

El error está en `infoEnviada.setText(array);`, dice: `Cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String[])`

---

Este es el Android Monitor:

```
03-06 16:54:45.814 6978-6978/com.example.pablo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at com.example.pablo.myapplication.encuesta$1.onClick(encuesta.java:59)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Este es el else que da error:

```
else
            {
                ListView listaresultados = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.reslt);
                ArrayList respuestas = new ArrayList();
                ArrayAdapter adaptador2 = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, respuestas);
                listaresultados.setAdapter(adaptador2);
                respuestas.add(strNombre);
                respuestas.add(curso);
                respuestas.add(strPregCuatro);
                respuestas.add(strPregCinco);
                Intent intent = new Intent (encuesta.this, res8.class);
                intent.putExtra("resultados", respuestas);
                startActivity(intent);
                Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡Encuesta enviada!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(pas);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String[])

Debes revisar que es el elemento `reslt` en tu Layout, probablemente no es un TextView.

```
 infoEnviada = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reslt);
```

Originalmente `reslt` era un `ListView` por eso marco este error.

---

#### Agregar valores de un array en un TextView:

Si es un array la opción sería convertir a String los elementos del Array:

```
String[] array = { "unu", "doi", "trei", "patru", "cinci" };
textView.setText(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Otra opción es usar `StringBuilder` para almacenar los valores del Array:

```
 String[] array = { "unu", "doi", "trei", "patru", "cinci" };

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String s: array) {
    builder.append(s); // Agrega elemento del array.
    builder.append(" "); //Separador.
}

textView.setText(builder.toString().trim()); //.trim() se usa para eliminar el último espacio.
```

---

Actualización:

Ahora el elemento reslt es un TextView por lo que el ListView ya no existe, no necesitamos las lineas que comento...

```
                //ListView listaresultados = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.reslt);
                ArrayList respuestas = new ArrayList();
                ArrayAdapter adaptador2 = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, respuestas);
                //listaresultados.setAdapter(adaptador2);
                respuestas.add(strNombre);
                respuestas.add(curso);
                respuestas.add(strPregCuatro);
                respuestas.add(strPregCinco);
                Intent intent = new Intent (encuesta.this, res8.class);
                intent.putExtra("resultados", respuestas);
                startActivity(intent);
                Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡Encuesta enviada!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(pas);
```

Comment: Es decir, borro el `getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("resultados");`?

Comment: No, realiza esto: String[] array = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("resultados");
    infoEnviada.setText(Arrays.toString(array)); pero revisa la segunda opción que propongo usando StringBuilder, seguramente te será de utilidad.

Comment: @PabloGonzalez esperá que tipo de elemento es reslt en tu layout? me parece que no es un TextView!

Comment: Si lo es: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pablo.myapplication.res8">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reslt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`

Comment: Pero ahora el problema es que, en el `else` me da crash, se detiene la aplicación. :( Ayuda!

Comment: mensaje en LogCat?

Comment: Ya lo mando en otra respuesta porque es largo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54908/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-pablo-gonzalez).

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas intentando invocar `setText()` con un array de Strings y eso no es posible.

Puedes elegir uno de los elementos del array que quieres pasarle al setText:

```
infoEnviada.setText(array[i]); //i = lugar de la cadena de texto en el array
```

O puedes mostrarlos todos con un bucle:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<=array.lenght ; i++){
    infoEnviada.setText(infoEnviada.getText().toString() + "\n" + array[i]);
}
```